# Possible to turn incoming emails to output the info into embeds in discord?

Tags: discord, embed

I run an Options Trading server on discord and would like to turn the alerts I receive via email to send the info in embeds into a channel. Right now I am using zapier which only shoots out text.

Comment: Yes it's possible.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.